# How can I access appsettings.json via PowerShell in a deployed Azure Web App?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-powershell

I need the ability to modify settings in appsettings.json in an Azure Web App that has already been deployed.

I can access AppConfig and Connectionstrings via PowerShell via the following command:

```
$webApp = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $websiteName
$webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings
$webApp.SiteConfig.ConnectionStrings
```

However, Is it possible to access appsettings.json via PowerShell?

Comment: You could, but then you'd be reading/writing a file that's part of your deployment.  Are you sure you want to do this, it wouldn't be recommended best practise?  I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but I cant think of any good reason to have a script update the static config file post deployment.  If you can tell us what the use case is perhaps we can suggest a better approach to achieving your goal.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you could add App Settings in your Azure Web App to override configuration values in the appsettings.json file. I assumed that your appsettings.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "OAuth": {
    "ApiKey": "ApiKey",
    "ApiSecret":"ApiSecret"
  }
}
```

Then, you could follow the scripts below to modify your settings:

```
$resourceGroupName="<your-resource-group-name>"
$websitename="<your-web-app-name>"
$webApp = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $websitename
$appsettingList=$webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings

#current appsettings
$appsettingList

$appsettings = @{}
ForEach ($k in $appsettingList) {
    $appsettings[$k.Name] = $k.Value
}

#modify the settings
$appsettings['OAuth:ApiKey'] = "<new-api-key>"
$appsettings['OAuth:ApiSecret'] = "<new-api-secret>"

#save appsettings
set-AzureRmWebApp -resourcegroupname $resourceGroupName -name $websitename -appsettings $appsettings
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, it seems like SiteConfig.AppSettings only returns App Settings which were defined via the Azure Portal.  Any custom additions I made to appSettings.json when developing locally aren't available via the method above after the site is published.  Any ideas how to gain access to them?